# Build errors after upgrading from Elasticsearch 5.5.0 to 7.5.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, elasticsearch, nest

I have recently upgraded `Elasticsearch.Net` and `NEST` in my application from Version 5.5.0 to 7.5.1 and I am getting a bunch of build errors. I've managed to resolve some of them but the following ones remain unclear to me:

**1) ElasticLowLevelClient.Msearch**

```
    MultiSearchRequest multiSearchRequest = new MultiSearchRequest { Operations = operations };
    MultiSearchResponseData response = Converter.ToMultiSearchResponseData(client.Msearch<byte[]>("articles", multiSearchRequest));
```

Where `operations` is of type `Dictionary<string, Nest.ISearchRequest>`, I am getting the following error:

**Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1061  'ElasticLowLevelClient' does not contain a definition for 'Msearch' and no accessible extension method 'Msearch' accepting a first argument of type 'ElasticLowLevelClient' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

**2) Elasticsearch.Net.PostData**

```
    SearchRequest request = new SearchRequest
    {
        Size = 1,
        Query = new QueryStringQuery { DefaultField = new Field("urlName"), Query = "(" + articleUrl + ")" },
    };
    ElasticsearchResponse<string> response = client.Search<string>("detailarticle", new PostData<object>(request));
```

I am getting the following error:

**Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1729  'PostData' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments**

**3) BulkUpdateOperation and PostDate:**

```
public void UpdateArticlesIndex(IEnumerable<ArticleUpdateModel> articles)
{
    if (articles == null || articles.Count() == 0)
        return;

    List<IBulkOperation> operations = new List<IBulkOperation>();
    foreach (var a in articles)
    {
        operations.Add(new BulkUpdateOperation<object, object>(a.DocumentId)
        {
            Index = "articles",
            Type = "_doc",
            Doc = a.Value,
        });
    }

    BulkRequest request = new BulkRequest
    {
        Operations = operations,
    };

    client.Bulk<string>(new PostData<object>(request));
}
```

I am getting the following two erros:

**Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0117  'BulkUpdateOperation<object, object>' does not contain a definition for 'Type'**

and

**Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1729  'PostData' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments**

I have tried messing with constructors and altering declarations but it did not yield any desired results. I have also looked into Elasticsearch documentation but did not find anything relevant

Any help about resolving those build errors would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. ElasticLowLevelClient.Msearch
>
>    MultiSearchRequest multiSearchRequest = new MultiSearchRequest { Operations = operations };
>    MultiSearchResponseData response = Converter.ToMultiSearchResponseData(client.Msearch<byte[]>("articles",
>    multiSearchRequest)); Where operations is of type Dictionary<string,
>    Nest.ISearchRequest>, I am getting the following error:
>
> Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error
> CS1061 'ElasticLowLevelClient' does not contain a definition for
> 'Msearch' and no accessible extension method 'Msearch' accepting a
> first argument of type 'ElasticLowLevelClient' could be found (are you
> missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Use `MultiSearch` instead of `Msearch`, wrap `MultiSearchRequest` in `PostData.Serialiable` and change the response type from `byte[]` to `BytesResponse`. Note that the low level client must be accessed from an instance of a high level client so that `MultiSearchRequest` is serialized correctly (*more specifically*, `ConnectionSettings` should be used, which is configured with a resolver that will use the correct formatter to JSON serialize `MultiSearchRequest` correctly)

```
var client = new ElasticClient();
MultiSearchRequest multiSearchRequest = new MultiSearchRequest { Operations = operations };
var response = client.LowLevel.MultiSearch<BytesResponse>("articles", PostData.Serializable(multiSearchRequest));
byte[] bytes = response.Body;
```

> 2. Elasticsearch.Net.PostData
>
>    SearchRequest request = new SearchRequest
>    {
>    Size = 1,
>    Query = new QueryStringQuery { DefaultField = new Field("urlName"), Query = "(" + articleUrl + ")" },
>    };
>    ElasticsearchResponse response = client.Search("detailarticle", new PostData(request));
>    I am getting the following error:
>
> Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error
> CS1729 'PostData' does not contain a constructor that takes 1
> arguments

Use `PostData.Serializable<T>(T data)` and return a `StringResponse`

```
var client = new ElasticClient();
var articleUrl = "example.com";

SearchRequest request = new SearchRequest
{
    Size = 1,
    Query = new QueryStringQuery { DefaultField = new Field("urlName"), Query = "(" + articleUrl + ")" },
};
var response = client.LowLevel.Search<StringResponse>("detailarticle", PostData.Serializable(request));
var str = response.Body;
```

> 3. 
>
> I am getting the following two erros:
>
> Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error
> CS0117 'BulkUpdateOperation<object, object>' does not contain a
> definition for 'Type'
>
> and
>
> Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error
> CS1729 'PostData' does not contain a constructor that takes 1
> arguments

Remove `Type` as types are going away in Elasticsearch and have been removed in NEST 7.x for bulk requests. The client will use `_doc` for APIs. Similar to the answer to 2, you should wrap `BulkRequest` in `PostData.Serializable<T>(T data)`